# 'random' numbers after exact numbers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make IF condition where I'm trying to print some text when number is 'correct'. The question is what if the condition can't have 'exact number' ? Like when you are finding everything (*) in linux system "find / -name *.mp3".

Here is my code, sure it do not work work for bad syntax but I put it here for example about my question:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        double b = 6.922083e-07;
        if (b == 6.922.*e-07) {
                printf("LOL \n");
        }
}
```

.* by this I mean everything other which do not matter.

Thank you very much, will be happy as an elephant if you can help me. I'm stupid and I just can't find it on google.

Comment: I don't understand your abbreviation: please show the exact code.

Comment: You can subtract the numbers and see if the difference is less than a threshold. It won't work with file names though.

Comment: remember that floating point numbers are an approximation.  Thus equality is not defined for them.  you should compare the difference to some epsilon.  For example, `fabs(b - b1) < epsilon` where epsilon might be defined to be 1E-7

Comment: @thurizas still, if the unclear code is intended to be `if (b == 6.922083e-07)` which is comparing a `double` variable with a `double` literal, AFAIK the conversion is guaranteed to be the same as with `double b = 6.922083e-07;`

Comment: @thurizas: I agree epsilon comparison should be used. On the other point I disagree: equality is defined for `double`.

Comment: Please don't tag with languages other than the one being used. Fixed.

Comment: You can't use the analogy of `ls abc*.*` that helps you find files starting with letters "abc" to numbers. Closest match to the task you want to achieve may be `if (b >= 6.922e-07 && b < 6.923e-07) ...`. This will help identify whether `b` starts with `0.0000006922` or not.

Comment: @BlueTune -- epsilon comparisons are only appropriate when they are appropriate. Don't forget, "nearly equal" (i.e., epsilon comparison) is **not** like equality. If a "nearly equal" b and b "nearly equals" c it does not follow that a "nearly equals" c. Ultimately, you have to know where your numbers come from and what you want to do with the result in order to decide how to compare floating point values sensibly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: `6.922.*e-07` doesn't make any sense. Did you mean `6.922e-07`?

Comment: @Ayxan The OP explicitly addresses what they mean by that notation in the question.

Comment: @Brian *"by this I mean everything other which do not matter."* I am still not sure what that means or what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to automate the task of getting the exponent:

```
int get_expo(double num){
  int n = 0;
  double number = num;
  if(number > 1 && number !=0){
      while (number > 1){
          number/=10;
          n++;
      }
      n-=1;
   }else{
       while(number < 1){
            number*=10;
            n++;
       }
       n = -n;
  }
  return n;
}
```

And then you can multiply that number by the 10^`exponent` plus 3 if you want three digit precision and then convert it to `int`:

```
#include <math.h>
int converted_num = d*pow(10 , get_expo(d) + 3);
if(converted_num == 6922)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Note that I used `6922` instead of `6.922`

Answer (score 0):

If you want "close enough" to be 1e-8, for example:

```
double eps = 1.0e-8;
if (b > (6.922083e-07 - eps) && b < (6.922083e-07 + eps)) {
    printf("LOL \n");
}
```